# Simple.OData.Client really slow

Tags: c#, performance, odata, odata-v4

I'm using Simple.OData.Client to query and update in our crm dynamics system.
But each query, insertion or update takes up to 10 seconds. It works like a charm on postman. That means that the server is not the problem.

Here is my Code:

Base Class

```
 public abstract class CrmBaseDao<T> where T : class
{
    protected ODataClient GetClient()
    {
        return new ODataClient(new ODataClientSettings(BuildServiceUrl())
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.Default.CrmUsername, Settings.Default.CrmPassword),
            IgnoreUnmappedProperties = true
        });
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        var client = GetClient();
        return await client.For<T>().FindEntriesAsync();
    }

    private string BuildServiceUrl()
    {
        return Settings.Default.CrmBaseUrl + "/api/data/v8.2/";
    }
}
```

Derived class:

```
    public void Insert(Account entity)
    {
        var task = GetClient()
            .For<Account>()
            .Set(ConvertToAnonymousType(entity))
            .InsertEntryAsync();

        task.Wait();

        entity.accountid = task.Result.accountid;
    }

    public void Update(Account entity)
    {
        var task = GetClient()
             .For<Account>()
             .Key(entity.accountid)
             .Set(ConvertToAnonymousType(entity))
             .UpdateEntryAsync();

        task.Wait();
    }

    private object ConvertToAnonymousType(Account entity)
    {
        return new
        {
            entity.address1_city,
            entity.address1_fax,
            entity.address1_line1,
            entity.address1_postalcode,
            entity.address1_stateorprovince,
            entity.he_accountnumber,
            entity.name,
            entity.telephone1,
            entity.telephone2
        };
    }

    public async Task<Account> GetByHeAccountNumber(string accountNumber)
    {
        return await GetClient().For<Account>()
            .Filter(x => x.he_accountnumber == accountNumber)
            .FindEntryAsync();
    }
```

The call:

```
 private void InsertIDocsToCrm()
    {
        foreach (var file in GetAllXmlFiles(Settings.Default.IDocPath))
        {
            var sapAccountEntity = GetSapAccountEntity(file);
            var crmAccountEntity = AccountConverter.Convert(sapAccountEntity);

            var existingAccount = crmAccountDao.GetByHeAccountNumber(crmAccountEntity.he_accountnumber);
            existingAccount.Wait();

            if (existingAccount.Result != null)
            {
                crmAccountEntity.accountid = existingAccount.Result.accountid;
                crmAccountDao.Update(crmAccountEntity);
            }
            else
                crmAccountDao.Insert(crmAccountEntity);
        }
    }
```

This whole function takes a very long time (30 sec+)
Is there any chance to speed that up?

Additionaly it does take a lot of memory?!

Thanks

Comment: Which line takes 10 seconds?

Comment: Every line from crmAccountDao - GetByHeAccountNumber; Update or Insert.. That means every API call

Comment: Try using asynchronous code asynchronously and see if that helps

Comment: that's not what I need

Comment: Why are you creating a new OData client every time? Don't do that. It will create a new HttpClient AND will fetch the OData metadata schema every time. Make it a singleton. I know you can also set the schema when instantiating to prevent the schema call but you will still be creating lots of HttpClients. You should rather create this outside the OData and pass it in so you are in control of the HttpClient lifecycle. HttpClients are meant to be used for the duration of the application...contrary to all the examples putting them in using blocks.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this might have to do with a size of schema. I will follow the issue you opened on GitHub.

UPDATE. I ran some benchmarks mocking server responses, and processing inside Simple.OData.Client took just milliseconds. I suggest you run benchmarks on a server side. You can also try assigning metadata file references to MetadataDocument property of ODataClientSettings.

Comment: Assigning metadata file to ODataClientSettings worked